# HTTP 3 - How to resolve this error

Tags: ssl, haproxy, makefile, http3

```
user@host:~/haproxy-2.7.1$ make TARGET=linux2.6.32 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_NGHTTP2=1 USE_QUIC=1
  CC      src/slz.o
  CC      src/ev_poll.o
  CC      src/ssl_sock.o
In file included from include/haproxy/quic_cc.h:33,
                 from include/haproxy/quic_conn.h:41,
                 from src/ssl_sock.c:68:
include/haproxy/quic_conn-t.h:540:30: error: field ‘level’ has incomplete type
  540 |  enum ssl_encryption_level_t level;
      |                              ^~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [Makefile:969: src/ssl_sock.o] Error 1
```

Comment: programming question should be asked on stackoverflow

Comment: It's not legal in C to forward-declare an `enum`.  The compiler will pick the underlying size of the enum based on the values in it, so the compiler cannot know what the size will be unless it also knows all the values.  In newer C++ standards you can explicitly declare the size of an enum and enum class and in that situation you can forward-declare but this is not available in C.